# Clear the kill ring in Bash (or kill an empty string with Ctrl-k)

Tags: bash

In Bash and other shells in emacs mode, there are these awesome kill/yank shortcuts (see `man readline`), for example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: "kill-line": this deletes (and save into a cut buffer) all the current line before the cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>: "yank" will paste under the cursor the last deleted content.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>: "yank-pop" will cycle through previous deleted content.

However I am in a situation where I want to:

1. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,
2. do stuff (type other commands),
3. and then paste back the original line, **but only if there was any content**!

In the current settings, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> on an empty line leaves the cut buffer unchanged, so hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> *does not* **restore** the original line.

I can't find how to clear this kill ring, is it doable (apart from switching to zsh...)?

Comment: A workaround is to kill the content+"a", then on paste delete that "a" character. Only works for automated binding (although I suppose that there's no reason to paste back an empty command when it's done manually)

Comment: Clever. It's indeed for automation. The aim was to *invisibly* use a feature of `tmux-resurrect`, which saves panel history by sending commands to the terminals (I wanted to back up partially filled lines). I found a way using `tput smcup`/`tput rmcup` which enters/quits a second terminal buffer O.o ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- kill ring is never cleared by readline library (used by bash), so there's no bindable command for that.